# What does “lament their teenagers’ noses” mean?

Tags: collocations

“*Parents lament their teenagers’ noses constantly in their phones.*”

Could you help me with the  understanding of the "lament their teenagers' noses" in this sentence? I am confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

**Lament** (... something) is used here as a *transitive verb* which can take an *expanded phrase* as its direct object. You can find similar examples here:

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lament_1

In other words, parents are unhappy with (or complain about) the fact that their children spend all the time with their noses buried in their phones.

Answer (score 0):

The partial quote in your title suggests that you're parsing the quote such that *their* refers to the parents. That is, the parents are using their own phones to lament their teenagers' noses. This gives rise to the odd interpretation.

It would be more natural to associate *their* with the teenagers. That is, it is more natural to take the antecedent of *their* to be “teenagers’” rather than “parents” (credit: [KarlG](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461689/what-does-lament-their-teenagers-noses-mean/461696#comment1113635_461696)). The *noses in the phones* then refers more naturally to where the teenagers are facing during mobile phone usage.

The lament is that teenagers are using their mobile phones excessively.

Comment: It might have been helpful to clarify that while the antecedent of the first _their_ is _parents_, _teenagers'_ is the antecedent of the second.

Comment: @KarlG That’s what I tried to do in the first and second paragraphs of my answer. I’ll edit.

Answer (score 0):

**to bury one's nose in** phrase [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/128408?rskey=Ol2Axd&result=3&isAdvanced=true#eid34220572)

> (d) to bury one's nose in: to become **intently occupied** with, spec. to
>   read studiously or intently; so to have one's nose in: to be **engrossed**
>   with

As in:

> “Parents lament their teenagers’ **burying their noses in** their
>   phones, to the exclusion of all else”